# Pandas rename specific columns and change dtype

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df1, where multiple columns contain the same subset of string characters. How do I make changes to these columns alone. For instance, remove the last three characters, change the column dtype, etc. I just want to be more comfortable making changes to columns with the same subset of characters (For example 'Session', shown below)

First Example:

```
df1:

Session1    Session2    Session3    Total
3.0         4.0         5.0         5.0
2.0         1.0         4.0         NaN

df2 (Intended Output):

Session1    Session2    Session3    Total
3           4           5           5.0
2           1           4           Nan
```

Second Example:

```
df1:

Session1    Session2    Session3    Total
3           4           5           5.0
2           1           4           Nan

df2 (Intended Out):

Sessi    Sessi    Sessi    Total
3        4        5        5.0
2        1        4        NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step would be to filter all the target columns you want. You can get them using

```
target_cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith('Session')]
```

Then you can apply any operation you want to those columns. For example, to change the data type you would do the following

```
df[target_cols] = df[target_cols].astype('int64')
```

**Edit:**
For your second point of renaming and removing the last three characters, you would use the rename function like this:

```
new_cols = [i[:-3] for i in target_cols]
df.rename(columns=dict(zip(target_cols, new_cols)), inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For your 1st point:**

```
n_columns_with_session = 3
# create the names of the target columns
cols = ["Session{}".format(i) for i in range(1,n_columns_with_session+1)]

# change the dtype of the target columns
df1[cols] = df1[cols].astype('int64')
```

---

**For your 2nd point:**

```
# create the new names
new_names_cols = ["Sess{}".format(i) for i in range(1,n_columns_with_session+1)]

# append "Total" name since you do not want to change this
new_names_cols.append('Total')    

# rename the columns
df1.columns = new_names_cols
```

Comment: Yes, but if I have 100 Session columns, I'd like to know to apply this to all columns that contain 'Session'